# Dynamic programming algorithm for sentence separation problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have to find a dynamic programming algorithm that solves the following problem, and I seem to be stuck:

> Given a function *f(w)* that returns the frequency at which the word *w* appears in the English language (0 <= *f(w)* <= 1), the algorithm divideSentence(*s*) where *s* is a string of letters with no spaces must return the value of *f(w)* of all words in *s* such that divideSentence is maximised. For example: divideSentence(helloworld) should return *f(hello)* + *f(world)*

I understand that with dynamic programming, I can limit the amount of calls to *f* by storing the intermediate values in say a hashmap, but the way I see it, there are 2^n ways to divide the sentence and I can't see how it's possible to find the solution without trying the 2^n different solutions, because *f(hell)*+*f(o)* != *f(hello)*. Although the teacher said it was possible to find an algorithm that finds the solution in O(n²) so clearly I'm missing something...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the dynamic programming solution for the above problem.

Let A[] be the array where A[i] means the answer considering the first i characters. So the final answer will be A[s.length()-1] (considering 0 based indexing) where s is the input string with no spaces.

Now the algorithm is as follows:

```
for i = 0:n
    for j = 0:i
        A[i]=max(A[i],A[j]+f(s.substring(j+1,i)))
    endfor
endfor

return A[n-1]
```

where n is the size of input string.
The final answer is stored in A[n-1].